# How to let ld link the function in a header file?

Tags: c

I have a self-defined function strlen() in lib.h

```
inline int strlen(char * String)
{
    register int __res;
    __asm__ __volatile__    (   "cld    \n\t"
                    "repne  \n\t"
                    "scasb  \n\t"
                    "notl   %0  \n\t"
                    "decl   %0  \n\t"
                    :"=c"(__res)
                    :"D"(String),"a"(0),"0"(0xffffffff)
                    :
                );
    return __res;
}
```

which is invoked in printk.c

```
#include "lib.h"
....
len=strlen(s);
```

and when I try to link printk.o,which is complied successfully by gcc

```
ld -b elf64-x86-64 -z muldefs -o system head.o main.o printk.o -T kernel.lds
```

I get

```
ld: printk.o: in function `vsprintf':
printk.c:(.text+0x7b1): undefined reference to `strlen'
```

I tried to use -L,but it doesn't work.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: `inline` works differently in C and C++.  Which one do you mean?

Comment: Just c.Thanks for reply and I update the label

Comment: Did you try to use `addr2line` to find out which line triggers the message? (I'm not sure but think this tool should be helpful.) -- Did you try to minimize the code into a [example] for us to reproduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, when you declare a function as `inline`, you must also declare it as `extern` in one (and only one) compilation unit.  So in one (and only one) of your .c files that has an `#include "lib.h"` add `extern int strlen(char *);` to get an extern definition of the inline function in that compilation unit to satisfy any link requests that did not get inlined (for whatever reason).

When you declare a function as `inline` without `extern`, it defines a version of the function that can be inlined into any call site it that compilation unit, if the compiler chooses to do so, but will not be included as a "standalone" function.  There is, however, no guarentee that any given call or use will be inlined (and generally, it will only be inlined if you enable optimization).  So if there are any non-inlined references to the function, you need to ensure that there is an extern definition of the function somewhere.

Comment: Thanks,it works.As far as I learnt, extern is used for variables across files.

Comment: `extern` is used to make a symbol globally visible across a program, rather than local to one compilation unit.